# Programmatically select QModelIndexes in QAbstractItemView

Tags: c++, qt, qmodelindex, qabstractitemview

I am trying to select items of abstract item view in Qt given their string values. I have already written function that finds any `QModelIndex` based on it's string content.

I am now trying to put all those `QModelIndex`es that I find into single selection. My method signature:

```
    // Will select all items that contain any of the strings
    // given by 1st argument
    virtual void selectItems(const QStringList&) override;
```

My implementation looks like this (but doesn't work properly):

```
void QAbstractItemViewResult::selectItems(const QStringList& list)
{
    if(list.size() > 0) {
        QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags flags = QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect;
        QItemSelection selection;
        Q_FOREACH(const QString text, list) {
            // Find index by string is a method I implemented earlier
            // The method works correctly
            QModelIndex index(findIndexByString(targetView_, list[0]));
            if(index.isValid()) {
                // This is an attempt to add model indx into selection
                selection.select(index, index);
            }
        }
        // When the selection is created, this should select it in index
        targetView_->selectionModel()->select(selection, flags);
    }
}
```

Problem is, this code always only selects first item in the list, eg. for `"B1","C1","A1"` it looks like this:

[image: image description]

The table has multi selection enabled:

[image: image description]

So how do I properly select multiple items programmatically? If you need the `findIndexByString`, it can be found here: https://github.com/Darker/qt-gui-test/blob/master/results/QAbstractItemViewResult.cpp#L5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>You clear the selection on every iteration.</del>

<del>Replace:</del>

```
QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags flags = QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect;
```

<del>by:</del>

```
QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags flags = QItemSelectionModel::Select;
```

**EDIT:** You pass `list[0]` instead of `text`:

```
findIndexByString(targetView_, list[0])
```

By the way, you should use a *const reference* in your loop:

```
Q_FOREACH(const QString &text, list) {
```

Or the native version if you use C++11 or superior:

```
for (const QSring &text : list) {
```

Comment: The flags are not used in the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. The main problem was probably the leftover `list[0]`. By the way, `ClearAndSelect` works well. I am not 100% but I think just `Select` would add new selection to existing selection.